# How to pause data factory tumbling window trigger if error occurs

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a tumbling window trigger for a pipeline.  If a window fails I do not want any additional windows ran until the failed window is addressed.  What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to achieve this in tumbling window trigger, but ADF provides various control and transform activities for you to come up with a combination method:

Involve a flag stored in a table/file to indicate the pipeline running status in a window, after each window execution, update this flag, then check this flag before execute another window run. You may need a [Lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) to fetch the value of this flag, an [IF activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity) to check the flag then a [Custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity)/[Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure) activity to update the value. HTH.